# Automatically Generating Microsoft Threat Modeling Tool model

Tags: xml, graphml, threat-model

I have a context model in [GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) that I want to import into the [Microsoft Threat Modeling Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49168) (MTMT).

After looking into the XML file used to represent the model it looks unreadable/hashed in some way.

I want to be able to generate a (generic) MTMT model from my graphml model

I am unable to find any documentation for the XML model of MTMT.

Does someone here have knowledge of the MTMT XML files that can help me with the parsing needed to create a tool to translate graphml to MTMT XML model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Open Threat Modeling Templates](https://github.com/matthiasrohr/OTMT),

> **Assigning new Templates to a Model:**
>
> Each threat model has its own template (.tm7 file) assigned to it via
>   a unique id. Unfortunately this ID cannot be changed from within the
>   tool itself. To adapt a new template to an existing model you
>   therefore need to change the template ID manually by opening the file
>   within a text editor. Luckily, both template and model are XML based.

by Matthias Rohr based on his [talk at OWASP AppSec EU 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5IPkuDnOGs&list=PLpr-xdpM8wG-Kf1_BOnT2LFZU8_SXfpKL&index=36) (slides [here](http://2016.appsec.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/AppSecEU2016-Matthias-Rohr-Practical-Threat-Modelling.pptx)).